# Disable UrbanAirship alerts

Tags: iphone, urbanairship.com

I want to ignore push notifications when the app is active. I am handling notifications as follows:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{ 
    if (application.applicationState != UIApplicationStateActive)
    {
        [[PushHelper shared] processPush: userInfo];
    }
}
```

But when app is active and device receives push notification, the UIAlertView with notification message appears. How can I disable default handling from UA?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem and found solution.
If define the delegate method **displayNotificationAlert:** of **UAPushNotificationDelegate** protocol with *empty* body, for example, then the automatic alerts will not be shown:

```
{   
   ...
   [[UAPush shared] registerForRemoteNotifications];
   [UAPush shared].pushNotificationDelegate = self;
   ...
}

- (void)displayNotificationAlert:(NSString *)alertMessage
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to do anything with the push notification itself just remove the `[[PushHelper shared] processPush: userInfo]` from your code

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{ 
   //nothing to do here
}
```

The didReceiveRemoteNotification method is only called when the app is running.

Comment: Awesome)) And how can I handle notification, when app returns from background after taping message from notification center?

Comment: you need to handle it in didFinishLaunchingWithOption method. The notification payload will be in the options dictionary